# I want to add my class name with each element in css using php

Tags: php, css

I want to create css parse type..

Parse will add my class name with each element in CSS.

For example I've the following CSS

```
.class1 {font-size:10px}
.class2 {font-style:italic}
body {height:100%}
html {width:100%}
```

After my parser it will be like this.

```
.myclass .class1 {font-size:10px}
.myclass .class2 {font-style:italic}
.myclass body {height:100%}
.myclass html {width:100%}
```

I already created a function but it doesn't work when @media queries come in CSS with nested elements.

Can anybody provide me good CSS parsers/solutions. I already tried available CSS parsers. those are not good enough for my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I recommend Sabberworm's [PHP-CSS-Parser](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser). I've used it myself and it's a fantastic tool. You can install it via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) by adding the code beneath to your composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "sabberworm/php-css-parser": "*"
    }
}
```

After installing it, it's pretty straight forward. You can either pass in your CSS-code from a variable containing the css in a string, or by reading a file from a specific directory. In my example, I will read it from a directory.

```
$oCssParser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser(file_get_contents('style.css'));
$oCssDocument = $oCssParser->parse();
```

Now you're ready to go. On this parser's Github, they actually do have an example of how to prepend an id to all selectors. I'll show you how to do it with a class.

```
$myClass = ".myclass";
foreach($oCssDocument->getAllDeclarationBlocks() as $oBlock) {
    foreach($oBlock->getSelectors() as $oSelector) {
        $oSelector->setSelector($myClass.' '.$oSelector->getSelector());
    }
}
```

Now you've prepended the class. Now you want to return the final product, don't you? That's easily done by using the built-in function `render()`. Something like this

```
$oFormat = Sabberworm\CSS\OutputFormat::create()->indentWithSpaces(4)->setSpaceBetweenRules("\n");
print $oCssDocument->render($oFormat);
```

And of course, if you want to output it to a file, you can do that as well using `file_put_contents()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you it is working... But when I load large css file like bootstrap. it takes too much execution time. Can I increase its execution time?

Comment: Thank you time problem is also solved by these codes.   $oSettings = Sabberworm\CSS\Settings::create()->withMultibyteSupport(false);
        $oParser = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser($css, $oSettings);

Comment: Great to hear. Please mark my answer as the solution! Cheers @ShakeelAhmed

Answer (score 0):

**css-way:**

```
*{
    background: #333;
}
```

**js-way:**

```
document.body.getElementsByTagName("*").classList.add("class");
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").classList.add("class");
```

**(php-way)**

```
echo "<script>document.getElementsByTagName('*').classList.add('yourclass');</script>"
```

Comment: I am not using javascript. I am using PHP and by the way I want to add myclass name to each element in css not only for *

Comment: this is the wildcard operator for all elements ... http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/W/wildcard_character.html

Comment: How can I use it in PHP?

Comment: He asked for a way to do it in PHP. If he wanted to do it in js you could just run an `.each()` in jQuery

Comment: php is serverside, how would you add classes to clientside objects?

Comment: Well OP is looking for a parser. Of course he could use jQuery to append a class to all elements, but since he's asking for a parser in PHP we talk about files including css content. So perhaps that you modify an existing css file and then replace it with a new one @Maurize

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should just use http://sass-lang.com/ to your product

Comment: This tool doesn't help the OP in this case. He wants to parse the CSS-file via PHP and prepend a class. Of course he could just open up the css file and edit it, but then this question would be pointless, wouldn't it?